# php regex capturing parantheses

Tags: php, regex

I can't capture what i want with capturing parantheses...
I'm searching in /hodsakers/marsh-zwartArray/d and i want to capture marsh-zwartArray but sometimes the last / is not present in what i'm searching.
I search and try many things =/ like :

```
(marshall[\s\S]*)\/
```

it work but if the last backslash is not present it doesn't.
I also try

```
(marsh[\s\S]*)(\/)?
```

in this case that's the opposite, it work without the last backslash but not anymore if there is one, it will get all the string and capture nothing =/
So i don't know how i can capture in both cases =/
Thanks for your help

Comment: Perhaps, just `/marsh[^\/]*/` is enough.

Comment: Do you want to match with all occurrences of 'marsh*' ? 
For example for the following case is going to match for twice if you example above /hodsakers/marsh-zwartArray/whatevermarsh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `[^\/]*` negated character class to match 0+ chars other than `/`:

```
/marsh[^\/]*/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qI7kW7/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was the negated character, problem is solved